# Expect conflicts with bash

Tags: bash, expect

I use expect in bash shell.But it seems that their syntax conflicts with each other's.Codes is shown below:

```
  1 #! /bin/bash
  2 
  3 SLJ_SERVERS=/data/qq_update/web/servers.conf
  4 
  5 >wrong_server.log
  6 while read line
  7 do
  8         if [[ "$line" == "s"* ]];then

  9                 export IP DIR
 10                 IP=`echo $line | awk -F: '{print $3}'`
 11                 DIR=`echo $line | awk -F: '{print $4}'`
 12                 echo "ip:$IP, dir:$DIR"
 13        
 14                 expect <<'END_OF_EXPECT'
                            exp_internal 1
 15                         spawn scp2 -o Port=36000 app27805@$env(IP):$env(        DIR)/socket/conf/GameServerConfig.xml ./
 16                         set password "app27805"
 17                         expect {
 18                                 "(yes/no)?" {
 19                                 send "yes\r"
 20                                 expect "password" {
 21                                 send "$password\r"
 22                                 }
 23                         }
 24                         "Password:" {
 25                                 send "$password\r"
 26                         }
 27                 }
 28                 interact
 29 END_OF_EXPECT
 30                 CONFIGURED_IP=`grep "ip" GameServerConfig.xml | awk -F\"         '{print $4}'`
 31                 echo "configured ip:$CONFIGURED_IP" >> configured_ip.log
 32                 if [[ "$IP" !=  "$CONFIGURED_IP" ]];then
 33                         echo "server:$DIR, correct ip:$IP, wrong ip:$CON        FIGURED_IP" >> wrong_server.log
 34                 fi
 35         fi
 36 
 37 done < $SLJ_SERVERS
```

Now I got an error said that:

[image: output after adding "exp_internal 1"]

How can I fix this problem.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because expect and bash are different languages. You wouldn't put java or assembly code into a bash script and magically get it to work. You have to invoke expect code with the `expect` interpreter. The contents of line 2 is just a bash comment: `#!` is only special as the first 2 characters of the file (see the execve man page)

Some other errors

- line 8: you are checking that $line is not the 3-character string <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>; if you want to skip comments, then `[[ $line != #* ]]`
- line 26: you open double quotes for the `-F` option and never close them: I assume you want double quote as the field separator. awk can do grep's work very capably so you don't need both.
- in bash, use `-eq/-ne` for numeric comparison and `=/!=` for strings -- did you not see any errors like "integer expression expected"?

```
while read line
do
    if [[ "$line" != #* ]];then
        export IP DIR
        read _ _ IP DIR <<< "$line"

        expect -c <<'END_OF_EXPECT'
            spawn scp2 -o Port=36000 app27805@$env(IP):$env(DIR)/socket/conf/GameServerConfig.xml ./
            set password "app27805"
            expect {
                "(yes/no)?" {
                    send "yes\r"
                    expect "password" {
                        send "$password\r"
                    }
                }
                "Password:" {
                    send "$password\r"
                }
            }
            interact
END_OF_EXPECT

        CONFIGURED_IP=$(awk -F \" '/ip/ {print $4; exit}' GameServerConfig.xml)
        if [ "$IP" != "$CONFIGURED_IP" ]; then
            echo "server:$DIR, correct ip:$IP, wrong ip:$CONFIGURED_IP"
        fi
    fi
done < $SLJ_SERVERS
```

Note that I single quoted the first END_OF_EXPECT token -- that puts the whole script in single quotes so the expect variables will be  handled by expect, not bash. Also the terminating END_OF_EXPECT token must not have any additional whitespace before or after it on the line.

Comment: :Sorry, I have modified my codes according your suggestion, I got a new error saying "expect: option requires an argument -- c", do you know what this mean? Thank you very much.

Comment: my error, just remove the `-c` and let expect read commands from stdin

Comment: I followed your advice, but failed to get the file "GameServerConfig.xml", maybe somewhere is wrong, can you give me more advices, really appreciate your help.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` above `spawn` so you can see what expect is doing

Comment: I captured the output after adding "exp_internal 1" above "spawn", can you check it for me one more time, really thank for your kindness.

Comment: what happens when you run the scp2 command from a command line? I can see that it's taking the password and then the scp2 command ends immediately